# SqlAlchemy and mysql-connector-python Docker file

Tags: python, docker, sqlalchemy, dockerfile, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to set up SqlAlchemy and mysql-connector-python with Docker. I put the following in requirements.txt but whenever I try to insert a record I get a Seg Fault, specifically 'Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)'. I am running this on ubuntu. Does anyone have a Docker file with this working? Do I need to do anything else other than put SqlAlchemy and mysql-connector-python in requirements.txt and do:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
# Update and install Python libraries
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y python3
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r /event_git/requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt has:

```
grpcio==1.11.0
grpcio-tools==1.11.0
mysql-connector-python==8.0.6
SqlAlchemy
```

For the Python code I am doing:

```
db_uri = ConfigFetcher.get_db_uri()
engine_obj = create_engine(db_uri, pool_recycle=3600)
SESSION_MAKER = sessionmaker(bind=engine_obj)
```

and then do:

```
    @staticmethod
    @contextmanager
    def get_session_no_expire_scope() -> Session:
        """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
        session = SESSION_MAKER(expire_on_commit=False)
        try:
            yield session
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()
```

I tried following https://mysql.wisborg.dk/2019/03/03/using-sqlalchemy-with-mysql-8/#Installing-MySQL-ConnectorPython-and-SQLAlchemy to no avail. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can You Please post the Error Log

Comment: @Gaurav, I just added the error in the description ('Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)') .

Comment: Still it's not enough to get it to the problem buddy. Because There is lot's of factor that can raise same issue

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Connector/Python is 8.0.16, please update your requirements.txt.

You can manually update the installed version by running: `pip3 install --upgrade mysql-connector-python`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I tried doing that but unfortunately any version after 8.0.5 has this issue. Do you know if there are any other steps that I need to take in the docker file?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. The key is that `import mysql.connector` needs to be at the top of the file where the create_engine is. Still not sure of the exact reason, but at the very least that seems to define `_CONNECTION_POOLS = {}`. If anyone knows why, please do give your thoughts.
Example of imports in python file:

```
import mysql.connector # need this _regardless_ of if you use it or not.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session
from sqlalchemy import engine
```